# Pysam view yield reads one at a time

Tags: python, bioinformatics, samtools, pysam

I'm trying to using `pysam` to filter a .bam file for mapping quality and excluding flags.

I know I can use `.fetch()` and iterate through reads that way, but I'm guessing it's faster to first use `pysam.view()`

However, when I try this on a large .bam, it appears to be trying to read in the entire file before returning any output. I want it to "yield" one read at a time. Is there a way to do this?

Here's my code:

```
for r in pysam.view('-q','255','-F','3840',input_bam):
    print(r)
    break
```

It's just hanging and never gets to the print statement because I believe it's trying to read in the whole .bam file before providing any output.